# Make colors in plot and imagesc the same

Tags: matlab

I have devised a visualization of my simulation in MATLAB which looks like this:

[image: simulation]

How do I make it so that `plot` and `imagesc` use the same colors? I want to be able to look at the legends in the plot and compare that line with the same color in the visualization to the left.

MWE:

```
field=randi(7,10);
distribution=rand(100,7);

h=figure(1);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
set(h, 'Position', [500 500 1000 500])
subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(field);
colormap('copper');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(distribution);
legend('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell how you want the colours to be ordered, but this will change the `colormap` from the default to `copper`.

```
%// sample data
field=randi(7,10);
distribution=rand(100,7);

h=figure(1);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
set(h, 'Position', [500 500 1000 500])

subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(field);
colormap('copper');
colorbar
h=subplot(1,2,2);
set(get(h,'Parent'),'DefaultAxesColorOrder',copper(7)) %// set the ColorOrder for this plot

plot(distribution);
legend('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you. For some reason this is not working for me. Could you please have a look at the code I appended in my question?

Comment: My typical luck! It doesn't work as in the line colors use the default coloring scheme :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it is using the default *color order*, i.e. it looks just like it did before. This is how the MWE looks for me: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hAdfa.png).

Comment: Yes, I just restarted MATLAB and the problem persists. Could be a bug? I am using version R2014a on OS X.

Comment: Error using set
Invalid default property for
Object Name: axes
Property Name: 'defaultAxesColorOrder'.

Comment: OK I think that's a 2014b thing not 2014a.

Comment: What happens when you run the code in my answer now?

Comment: Still doesn't work, and I have now installed 2014b. I also tried 'defaultAxesColorOrder' and it doesn't throw an error anymore, but doesn't work either.

Comment: @Pickett I think I've figured it out, try now.

Comment: Yep, you did it! Thanks a lot for not giving up on it!